# After upgrading to Catalina `csrutil disable` doesn't seem to work anymore

Tags: catalina, permission, icon, sip

I just upgraded to Catalina and now the *csrutil disable* command no longer lets me edit locked folders. I mostly just want to customize the icons for native apps like Finder and Launchpad. I typed in `csrutil status` and it confirms that it is disabled, but I no longer have permission to edit these apps or add to their resources folders.

The upgrade is very recent, but has anyone found a solution yet?

Comment: You have to use csrutil disable from Recovery Mode.

Comment: System files are read only regardless of SIP status on Catalina.